# Action view template error when running cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara, bdd

Here is a cucumber scenario:

```
Scenario: Login
Given the user is on Login page
When I sign in
```

My step definition:

```
When /I sign in/ do
  within("#mypage") do
    fill_in 'login_id', :with => 'ccd'
    fill_in 'password', :with => 'coffee'
  end
  click_button 'Login'
  visit '/feedbacks/'
end
```

When I run cucumber, I get the following error:

```
Scenario: Login                 # features\heartbeat_tests.feature:20
Given the user is on Login page # features/step_definitions/heartbeat_definitions.rb:5
When I sign in                  # features/step_definitions/heartbeat_definitions.rb:18
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (ActionView::Template::Error)
D:/shoutout_web/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:256:in          
`_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__124036717_28160832'
```

Comment: You're going to have to share what's at application.html.erb line 256. Also what is line 18 of heartbeat_definitions.rb?

Comment: Hi @Geoff Here it is line 250 to 256 of appliaction.html.erb               <%if session[:pagetobeloaded] != "category_edit" %>
<div class="demo1">
<div class="ui-widget">
    
  <select id="combobox1"  >
  <%@cityname.each do |city| %>
     <option value="<%=city%>"><%=city%> </option>
  <%end%>

Comment: Definitions.rb                                                                When /I sign in/ do

  within("#mypage") do
    fill_in 'login_id', :with => 'ccd'
    fill_in 'password', :with => 'coffee'
  end
  click_button 'Login'
  visit '/feedbacks/'

end

Comment: Can you edit the original question with those lines of code? It's hard to read them in comments. Please make sure to include the line numbers for Definitions.rb too.